# Htaccess mod_rewrite for multilanguage website

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**DESCRIPTION & SAMPLE DATA**

There are 2 languages Lithuanian (default) and English.

I have parameter `$lang` which can have values `lt` or `en`.

I have 3 files: `users.php`, `nav.php`and `arrays.php`

`arrays.php` looks like:

```
$navItems = array(
                array(
                    'slug'      => "index.php",
                    'title_en'   => "Home",
                    'title_lt'   => "Pradžia"
                ),                   
                array(
                    'slug'    => "users.php?lang=en",
                    'title_en'   => "English",
                    'title_lt'   => "Anglų"
                ),
                array(
                    'slug'    => "users.php?lang=lt",
                    'title_en'   => "Lithuanian",
                    'title_lt'   => "Lietuvių"
                )
            );
```

`users.php` looks like:

```
if (!empty($_GET['lang'])) {
    $_COOKIE['lang'] = $_GET['lang'] === 'en' ? 'en' : 'lt';
} else {
    $_COOKIE['lang'] = 'lt';
}
setcookie('lang', $_COOKIE['lang']);

<?php include('includes/nav.php'); ?>
```

`nav.php` looks like:

```
if ( $_COOKIE['lang'] == "en") {
    $lang = "en";
} else {
    $lang = "lt";
}

$title = "title_" . $lang;
?>

<nav class="top-header-nav">
    <ul>
        <?php
            foreach ($navItems as $item) {
                echo "<li><a href=\"$item[slug]\">$item[$title]</a></li>";
            }
        ?>
</ul>
</nav>
```

So `nav.php` generate HTML buttons like: `<a href="users.php?lang=en">English</a>`

---

**WHAT I NEED**

After choosing English language my URL in address bar looks like: `http://localhost/users.php?lang=en`

I need to achieve `http://localhost/en/users/` instead of above.

---

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

I'm testing it on WAMP.

My `.htaccess` file for now looks like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /  

RewriteRule ^(en|lt)/(.*)$  $2?lang=$1&%{query_STRING} [L]
```

But It not working, also I've tried like this: `RewriteEngine on ^(en|lt)?(.*)$ $2?lang=$1` but unsuccessfully too.

Have you ideas?

Comment: maybe you forgot a `.php` in the replacement. `RewriteRule ^(en|lt)/([^/]+)/?$  $2.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: You can also replace `{query_STRING} [L]` with `[QSA,L]`

Comment: @Deadooshka thank you for comment, but not worked. If I manually enter `http://localhost/en/` It working, but If I click button like this `<a href="users.php?lang=en">English</a>` It store in address bar `http://localhost/en/index.php?lang=en`

Comment: @Capsule not worked too.

Comment: make it root-relative `<a href="/users.php?`

Comment: @Deadooshka the same, not worked.

Comment: so why didn't you change the `$navItems`? `'slug' => '/en/users/' ... '/lt/users/'`